# Ruby: when altering string's content using []= and out of the range

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie at Ruby, and I'm reading the ["Ruby Programming Language"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516178), when encountered section "3.2.4 Accessing Characters and Substrings", there is an example illustrate using `[]=` to alter the string content on Page 56 and 57:

```
s = 'hello'; # Ruby 1.9
....
....
s[s.length] = ?! # ERROR! Can't assign beyond the end of the string
```

Yes, it's true, you cannot assign beyond the end of the string.
But, when I played with it on the IRB, I got a different result:

```
irb(main):016:0> s[s.length] = ?!
=> "!"
irb(main):017:0> s
=> "hello!"
```

> Ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I don't like this behavior at all and think that it definitely should give an `IndexError`. In my 1.9.2p180 it works just as you show in both `irb` and in a .rb-file.

Answer (score 1):

This book is from 2008, and the example was using Ruby 1.8, in 1.9.2 it works perfectly:

```
# Ruby 1.8.7-p352
s = 'hello'
s[s.length] = ?!
puts s

# => IndexError: index 5 out of string
#      method []= in ruby.rb at line 3
#      at top level in ruby.rb at line 3
```

```
# Ruby 1.9.2-p290
s = 'hello'
s[s.length] = ?!
puts s

# => hello!
```

Comment: maybe the context of this example is for ruby 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Nice pickup it does look like a Ruby 1.8 vs 1.9 thing. It looks like in 1.9 the String `[]=` is treated in a similar way as the String `insert` method.

You can use the insert method to insert a string **before** a particular character in another string. So let's take our string "hello" as an example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :238 > s = "hello"
 => "hello" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :239 > s.length
 => 5 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :240 > s.insert(s.length, " world")
 => "hello world"
```

But now lets try to use insert to insert into `s.length + 1`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :242 > s = "hello"
 => "hello" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :243 > s.insert(s.length + 1, " world")
IndexError: index 6 out of string
    from (irb):243:in `insert'
```

We get the same behaviour if we use the `[]=` method:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :244 > s = "hello"
 => "hello" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :245 > s[s.length] = " world"
 => " world" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :246 > s
 => "hello world" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :247 > s = "hello"
 => "hello" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :248 > s[s.length + 1] = " world"
IndexError: index 6 out of string
    from (irb):248:in `[]='
```

So, Ruby 1.9 is clever enough to recognise when you're trying to assign to an index that is just past the end of the string and automagically treats that as an insertion/concatenation. Whether or not this behaviour is desirable probably depends on personal preference, it is certainly good to be aware that it is the behaviour you can expect.

Comment: "automagically treats that as an insertion/concatenation" -- this explains a lot, thx

Comment: I tried to find the behavior in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c in the `rb_str_aset` but since I couldn't in a couple of minutes I gave up. I still think that this is inconsistent behavior and if it even should be there then it should have been documented.